# asp.net disabled jquery dialog modal button after postback

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, modal-dialog, updatepanel

I'm using [jQuery Dilog Modal](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) in ASP.NET page but when the page do **postback** the button that open the dialog modal loses the jQuery behavior...

I tested the button inside and outside of UpdatePanel, but I got the same error...

How can I maintain the jQuery after postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wiring up your button inside `pageLoad()` instead of `$(document).ready()`, which is native to .NET and will fire on each postback.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
    $('#button').click();
}
```

Beware that `pageLoad()` is **not** a permanent replacement for `$(document).ready()` when using ASP.NET, since they behave very differently, but in this case it just might solve your problem.

Comment: In your code, where you use `$(document).ready(function() { ... Your jQuery code ... }` today, just replace that with `function pageLoad(sender, args) { ... Your jQuery code ... }` and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks... this work... But I have another question if you can answer... Why function pageLoad(sender, args) is excecuted if I never call it?

Comment: `pageLoad` is part of .NET and fired upon every postback. You don't have to call it yourself :)